# Fail to compile library - openalpr

Tags: c++, macos, openalpr

I'm trying to install openalpr on MacOSX El Capitan 10.11.6
and when I tried to run 'make' command, it goes smoothly until it reaches 55% which it generates following errors. Here are the steps that I followed (https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/wiki/Compilation-instructions-(OS-X))

[error output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIgJ9.png)

The remaining outputs are:

```
In file included from /Users/Anonymous/openalpr/src/daemon.cpp:8:
In file included from 
/Users/Anonymous/openalpr/src/video/logging_videobuffer.h:5:
In file included from /usr/local/include/log4cplus/logger.h:36:
In file included from 
/usr/local/include/log4cplus/spi/appenderattachable.h:33:
In file included from /usr/local/include/log4cplus/appender.h:36:
/usr/local/include/log4cplus/helpers/pointer.h:134:21: error: cannot 
initialize object parameter of type 'const 
log4cplus::helpers::SharedObject' with an expression of type 
'log4cplus::spi::Filter'
                pointee->removeReference();
                ^~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/log4cplus/helpers/pointer.h:152:17: note: in 
instantiation of member function 
'log4cplus::helpers::SharedObjectPtr<log4cplus::spi::Filter>::~SharedObjectPtr' requested here
            SharedObjectPtr<T> (rhs).swap (*this);
                ^
/usr/local/include/log4cplus/helpers/pointer.h:147:30: note: in instantiation of member function 'log4cplus::helpers::SharedObjectPtr<log4cplus::spi::Filter>::operator=' requested here
            return this->operator = (rhs.pointee);
                         ^
   /usr/local/include/log4cplus/appender.h:211:62: note: in instantiation of member function 
   'log4cplus::helpers::SharedObjectPtr<log4cplus::spi::Filter>::operator=' requested here
    void setFilter(log4cplus::spi::FilterPtr f) { filter = f; }
                                                         ^
1 warning and 7 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/alprd.dir/daemon.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/alprd.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2`
```

Comment: its 50%, not 55% & title should be "Fail to compile the library"

Comment: so just click [edit] on your post

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing the atomic library. You can find it [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc%2B%2B/libstdc%2B%2B-api-4.5/a00737_source.html). Place it alongside all the other c++ include files in your system.